# Populating Woocommerce Variation Custom Select Field Options From Database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add custom select field for my variations, so each variation will have two select field and there value is interrelated i.e based on the option selection of first select field, the second select field will fetch result from database and populate it with those options.

So far I am able to create a custom select fields and in first select field I am able to pull the options from database, however I am not sure if that is the correct way or not.

To fetch data for second select field, I am using ajax but it seems to be not working.

Here is my code for custom field in my functions.php file:

```
$vvr = array(
    '0.01 TO 0.03 CT' => __( '0.01 TO 0.03 CT', 'woocommerce' ),
    '0.04 TO 0.07 CT' => __( '0.04 TO 0.07 CT', 'woocommerce' ),
    '0.08 TO 0.14 CT' => __( '0.08 TO 0.14 CT', 'woocommerce' ),
    '0.15 TO 0.17 CT' => __( '0.15 TO 0.17 CT', 'woocommerce' ),
    '0.18 TO 0.22 CT' => __( '0.18 TO 0.22 CT', 'woocommerce' ),
    '0.22 To 0.29 CT' => __( '0.22 To 0.29 CT', 'woocommerce' )   
);

woocommerce_wp_select( array( 
    'id'          => '_diam_one[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
    'label'       => __( 'Enter First diamond', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'class'       => 'diamtype',
    'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_diam_one', true ),
    'options' => $vvr
) );
```

The above code is perfect for creating predefined options, as I am adding them manually in my functions.php file.

But I want to pull these option from my custom table inside wordpress db, below is the code which I was using to fetch those option from my custom table.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT distinct type FROM diamonds');

foreach($result as $row)

{
    $vvr[$row->type] =$row->type;
}
```

The above code is also pulling the data from my custom table but as you can see its not following the WP standards to add those options.

Now based on the selection of this select field I want to fetch data to my another select field from my custom table which I've already added just like the first one.

[image]

You can see the above screenshot, So can anyone help my out with the best way I can achieve this functionality as I don't want to list the those option through hard code.